# Proving -(a+b) = (-a) + (-b) using A1-A4 only.

Tags: analysis

A1: + is commutative.
A2: + is associative.
A3: 0 is an additive identity.
A4: -a is an additive inverse of a.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}-(a+b) &= \bigl(a+ (-a)\bigr) + \bigl(b+(-b)\bigr) + -(a+b)\\ &= (-a)+(-b) + \bigl((a + b) + -(a+b)\bigr)\\ &= (-a) + (-b)\end{align}$$

Comment: +1: I've altered your formatting to make it look a little nicer. Hopefully it meets with your approval.

Answer (score 1):

The equality

> $-(a+b)=(-b)+(-a)$

holds in general in any (additive) group. If the group is commutative …